# Does adding audits produce less biased data?

Tags: experiment-design, survey, bias, bias-correction

My team made a survey about sexual behaviors among college students in China, and the result looks unreasonable<sup>1</sup>, so we suspect that many of the participants aren't serious when filling out the questionnaires.

I'm considering adding audits in the questionnaires. For example,

> On average, how often do you have sex with others?
>
> - never
> - twice a year or less
> - more than twice a year, less than or equal to once a month
> - more than once a month, less than or equal to once a week
> - more than once a week, less than or equal to once a day
> - more than once a day, less than or equal to once an hour
> - more than once an hour

Since it's practically impossible for one to have sex more than once an hour, if a participant chose `more than once an hour`, we'll mark their response as invalid and ignore it when performing analysis.

Or maybe a more generic one like:

> Monnow Bridge (Welsh: Pont Trefynwy) in Monmouth, Wales, is the only
>   remaining fortified river bridge in Great Britain with its gate tower
>   standing on the bridge. It crosses the River Monnow 500 metres (1,600
>   ft) above its confluence with the River Wye. Please choose Disagree below.
>
> - Agree strongly
> - Agree
> - Disagree
> - Disagree strongly

If a participate chose anything other than `Disagree`, it indicates that they wasn't paying attention when taking the survey, and thus their response would be filtered out.

My question is: does adding such audits produce less biased data? if so, will it have a large impact? also, will it introduce extra noise?

<sup>1: I'm not going to disclose the accurate figures, but it looks like "0% of the participants had sex between once a week and once a day, while ~5% of them had sex more than once a day". Also note that the Chinese society is quite conservative.</sup>

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that your respondents may have been a volunteering subset in the population? Maybe those who answered were particularly "active", while those who are not did not dare producing any answer. How did you collect the data ? web survey ? Was there a nominative sample before running the data collection or was it anonymous ?

Comment: @g3o2 We did an anonymous web survey, since it's the most economical way to us. We know a web survey is generally more biased, since the respondents are usually not sampled properly, but we don't have enough time and money to distribute paper questionnaires in the real world. Anyway, I think it's impossible to have _completely_ unbiased data; I'm just trying to make it as less biased as possible on the current circumstances.

Comment: The anonymous web survey is not the problem, it is the absence of a sample drawn from the population you want to study, at least you can't be sure what you're gonna get. Hence, the "weird" results. Have you included some demographic and social background related questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extra noise...no. Throwing away data from people who clearly aren't taking the survey seriously certainly won't make things any worse.

I can envision some very strange circumstances where this could add bias, so it's impossible to say that it wouldn't. For example, if people who answer questions unrealistically make up a disproportionate number of those who *would* answer a specific way if they were answering truthfully, then you might be biasing against this response. However, given that the alternative is to accept answers that are almost definitely nonsensical, there was likely much more bias to begin with before you discarded these answers. So you can expect to reduce the bias, even if you can't guarantee it.

*However*, the fact that you've collected data, examined the results, and then decided to re-run the experiment can be a source of bias. Exactly what distribution of responses would you have needed to believe that your survey was valid? If you think there's no conceivable way that 5% of the participants could respond a certain way, you're introducing a prior assumption that may not be valid. It would be best to include the audit questions the first time, rather than adding them in after you've already reviewed the first round of responses.

Comment: As soon as we are talking about 5% of a sample, throwing away data will influence study results.

Answer (score -2):

Unless the objective of your survey is finding out about lying behaviours, adding any "audits" or lie detectors is a really bad idea. It is okay to ask knowledge questions, but do not encourage lying behaviour.

Avoid formulating weak questions, even if they are meant to be "audits". In your second example, the attentive respondent will follow exactly your advice and disagree because that's what you've asked for. In the first example, the last option does not make any sense at all, for that would leave no time for anything but ...

In addition, you receive a "controlled" garbage response, now what?

- ignore the response in your study: very dangerous strategy. As soon as the proportion becomes significant, the study is no less flawed than without the "audit".
- impute it with a more plausible value, sure, but how? If you don't know what causes the bad item response, it is very difficult to impute it without introducing another bias;
- disclose it in your study: the preferable option, but hopefully the phenomenon is rare enough to avoid the readers from concluding the problem was the survey itself;

Therefore, the only viable solution consists in studying your topic well and eventually come up with a set of good questions. Test the questionnaire before-hand on a few subjects (e.g. a sample of 10-20) and then learn from that test run to revise the questionnaire accordingly. Seek feedback from peers who ran similar surveys as well. Finally, run your full data collection.

Should any weird significant response phenomenon arise, you should always ask yourself:

- what characterizes those people who provided the bad answers? If there's a pattern, you can resort to imputation;
- could the formulation of the question and the response items be improved?
- is the topic overly sensitive? May this lead a certain subsample not to respond at all to either question or survey?
- is the questionnaire too long?
- is the survey addressed to the right audience? how to ensure that those who respond are actually from the population you are studying?
- who did not respond to the survey and what are the potential reasons?
- is the sample design and the collection mode appropriate?

Never assume that the questionnaire and the survey design would not introduce bias.

Comment: -1. You don't seem to understand the purpose of the items in question, which is to check for subjects who aren't paying attention. You also seem to believe that it's possible to design a questionnaire such that subjects are guaranteed to play along. As a psychologist, I disagree.

Comment: The survey is about studying sexual behaviours in China, not about checking the subjects' attention capacity or deficit.

Comment: True, but people's inattentiveness and apathy will affect their responses to questions about sexual behavior. So although these annoyances aren't of primary interest, accounting for them allows one to get more accurate answers about the primary topic.

Comment: A lot of assumptions. After all, what do we know about the survey design of the study performed here above? What was the unit non-response? How big the sample? What collection mode? etc. All this influences the quality of the data collection.